# Is it possible to use instances of an object created in a class from another class? I

Tags: java, netbeans

My project has a few windows, and in each I have to initialize the same values in each jFrame. Is it possible to create a class and inherit every instance? 
I know how to do it using mySql, but it has to be done within Netbeans.
Thanks in advance.

```
//Pequeña base de datos local que guarda los médicos  de Clínica Haskell (R)
Medico medico1 = new Medico("Maidana", "Juan", 123, new Fecha(3, 2, 1980), 1234);
Medico medico2 = new Medico("Miranda", "Jorge", 456, new Fecha(3, 2, 1980), 1234);
Medico medico3 = new Medico("Masmut", "Julian", 789, new Fecha(3, 2, 1980), 1234);    
ObraSocial os1 = new ObraSocial(1, "Boreal");
ObraSocial os2 = new ObraSocial(2, "Asunt");
ObraSocial os3 = new ObraSocial(3, "Prensa");    
Paciente paciente1 = new Paciente("Perez", "Juan", 123, new Fecha(3, 2, 1980), 1234, os1);
Paciente paciente2 = new Paciente("Patrón", "Jorge", 456, new Fecha(3, 2, 1980), 1234, os2);
Paciente paciente3 = new Paciente("Pons", "Julian", 789, new Fecha(3, 2, 1980), 1234, os3);    
Medicamento medicamento1 = new Medicamento(1,"Bayaspirina", "Bayer");
Medicamento medicamento2 = new Medicamento(2,"Cafiaspirina", "Bayer");
Medicamento medicamento3 = new Medicamento(3,"Ibupirac 600", "Pfizer");
```

Comment: `Is it possible to use instances of an object created in a class from another class?` ---> Yes. Also, no need of inheritance. Just check thee access level of the class in which you're writing common code!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: yes,it is. But I suggest to separate the UI part from the data model.

- All the instances/ classes you show in your question should be part of a model.
- A controller could be used to forward the information from the model to the UI.

Be aware that **inherit every instance** as you mentioned in your question is not happening. Its more about classes and not instances,  [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) you can read more about this topic.